# from array to range by step in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands, partition-by

The array of numbers should be transferred to ranges to compress the number of records.
This is an example:

Current:

| L2PARAM_ID | A_AXIS_RANGE |
| --- | --- |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 10 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 20 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 70 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 80 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 90 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 100 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 110 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 160 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 170 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 180 |

Needed:

| L2PARAM_ID | A_AXIS_RANGE_FROM | A_AXIS_RANGE_TO | A_AXIS_RANGE_STEP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 10 | 20 | 10 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 70 | 110 | 10 |
| CL_L2_Params_2688303 | 160 | 180 | 10 |

Seems quite simple with the windows functions, but so far hard to get the 3 'groups'. Any help would be appreciated

tried so far:

```sql
with axis_by_step as (
    select
      L2PARAM_ID,
      A_AXIS_RANGE,
      LEAD (A_AXIS_RANGE) OVER (PARTITION BY L2PARAM_ID ORDER BY A_AXIS_RANGE) - A_AXIS_RANGE AS STEP_3,
      COUNT (A_AXIS_RANGE) OVER (PARTITION BY L2PARAM_ID) cnt,
      CASE WHEN
        COUNT (A_AXIS_RANGE) OVER (PARTITION BY L2PARAM_ID) = 1
        THEN A_AXIS_RANGE
        ELSE LEAD (A_AXIS_RANGE) OVER (PARTITION BY L2PARAM_ID ORDER BY A_AXIS_RANGE)
        END AS TO_3
    from PMDM_LRSV_CL_L2_PARAM_PREP_MULTI_AXIS
)
select *
from axis_by_step
```

Comment: Sounds like gaps and islands problem. Not sure where that 10 is coming from though.

Comment: gaps and islands? 10 is the step. So eg from 70 you go by steps from 10 to 110, covering the values 70, 80, 90, 100 and 110

Comment: Yes, gaps and island Iis the name of problem you are facing, @FritsNagtegaal . It even has its own tag where you can find plenty of related questions: [[tag:gaps-and-islands]]

Answer (score 2):

In this specific gaps-and-islands problem you need to:

- look for when the axis_range between consecutive rows changes by more than 10, given this is your prefixed step, and get to flag with 1 those rows
- compute a running sum over your flag value, in order to generate a new partitioning inside the "*L2PARAM_ID*" partition
- aggregate exploiting your just generated partition, alongside with "*L2PARAM_ID*"

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN A_AXIS_RANGE 
                     - LAG(A_AXIS_RANGE) OVER(PARTITION BY L2PARAM_ID ORDER BY A_AXIS_RANGE) > 10
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END AS change_part 
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, 
           SUM(change_part) OVER(PARTITION BY L2PARAM_ID ORDER BY A_AXIS_RANGE) AS part 
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT L2PARAM_ID, 
       MIN(A_AXIS_RANGE) AS A_AXIS_RANGE_FROM,
       MAX(A_AXIS_RANGE) AS A_AXIS_RANGE_TO,
       10                AS AXIS_RANGE_STEP
FROM cte2 
GROUP BY L2PARAM_ID, part
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LLfKsTL1).

Comment: Thank you so much @lemon , the computing of a running sum was the part that helped me out. Actually the AXIS_RANGE_STEP can be other than 10, so I had to tweak it a little, but that was easy to calculate. Thanks!!!!!!